# rviz not compiling mac osx

Tags: ros, rviz, osx, mac

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to install ROS on mac after having traded from ubuntu. I found some of these inconsistencies in the latest boost libraries.

1 . The latest boost library does not offer tr1/* hence rospack fails to compile which uses this library. Got around this by including the older boost version libraries.

2 . The rviz package does not build with the following errors. I tried including the older version for this but roscpp fails to build as there is some problem with that particular older version of boost. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
In file included from /Users/sreeharshacs/ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/image_view/main.cpp:42:
In file included from /Users/sreeharshacs/ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/image_view/image_view.h:31:
In file included from /Users/sreeharshacs/ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/rviz/ogre_helpers/qt_ogre_render_window.h:36:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4_4/include/OGRE/OgreColourValue.h:31:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4_4/include/OGRE/OgrePrerequisites.h:315:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4_4/include/OGRE/OgreStdHeaders.h:114:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4_4/include/OGRE/Threading/OgreThreadHeaders.h:30:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4_4/include/OGRE/Threading/OgreThreadHeadersBoost.h:30:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/recursive_mutex.hpp:16:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/recursive_mutex.hpp:23:
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/pthread_mutex_scoped_lock.hpp:33:26: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
            void check() BOOST_NOEXCEPT
                             ^
/usr/local/include/boost/config/detail/suffix.hpp:959:26: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_NOEXCEPT'
#  define BOOST_NOEXCEPT noexcept
                         ^
In file included from /Users/sreeharshacs/ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/image_view/main.cpp:42:
In file included from /Users/sreeharshacs/ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/image_view/image_view.h:31:
In file included from /Users/sreeharshacs/ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/rviz/ogre_helpers/qt_ogre_render_window.h:36:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4_4/include/OGRE/OgreColourValue.h:31:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4_4/include/OGRE/OgrePrerequisites.h:315:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4_4/include/OGRE/OgreStdHeaders.h:114:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4_4/include/OGRE/Threading/OgreThreadHeaders.h:30:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4_4/include/OGRE/Threading/OgreThreadHeadersBoost.h:31:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/condition.hpp:13:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp:16:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable.hpp:12:
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:213:13: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
            {
            ^
In file included from /Users/sreeharshacs/ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/image_view/main.cpp:42:
In file included from /Users/sreeharshacs/ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/image_view/image_view.h:31:
In file included from /Users/sreeharshacs/ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/rviz/ogre_helpers/qt_ogre_render_window.h:36:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4_4/include/OGRE/OgreColourValue.h:31:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4_4/include/OGRE/OgrePrerequisites.h:315:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4_4/include/OGRE/OgreStdHeaders.h:114:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4_4/include/OGRE/Threading/OgreThreadHeaders.h:30:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4_4/include/OGRE/Threading/OgreThreadHeadersBoost.h:31:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/condition.hpp:13:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp:16:
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable.hpp:82:43: error: expected unqualified-id
            check_for_interruption.check();
                                          ^
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable.hpp:116:43: error: expected unqualified-id
            check_for_interruption.check();
                                          ^
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable.hpp:193:47: error: expected unqualified-id
                check_for_interruption.check();
                                              ^
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable.hpp:423:45: error: expected unqualified-id
              check_for_interruption.check();
                                            ^
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272219/rviz-not-compiling-mac-osx/) by [harsha336](https://answers.ros.org/users/32137/harsha336/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to solve this particular issue by adding

```
#ifdef __APPLE__ 
#define __ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES 0
#endif
```

before the first include in `rviz/src/image_view/main.cpp`.
See also this [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665095/xcode-error-compiling-c-expected-member-name-or-after-declaration-specifie).

---

Originally posted by [dischu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29049/dischu/) with karma: 56 on 2017-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1